# ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible Python

Tags: python, css, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I'm new to Python and Selenium and I've come across an issue when trying to click on a button via webdriver.

The HTML of the div I'm trying to click through is:

```
<div class="">
    <form method="POST">
    <input class="hide" id="accept" name="accept" type="text" value="yes" readonly="">
    <a href="/" class="btn btn-red">
         <div class="svg-group group   icn-bg-circle" data-png-fallback="">
         <svg width="8" height="8">
         <use xmlns:xlink=" " xlink:href=""></use>
         </svg>
         </div>
         Decline
     </a>
     <button class="btn btn-green" type="submit">
         <div class="svg-group group   icn-bg-circle" data-png-fallback="">
             <svg width="8" height="8">
             <use xmlns:xlink="" xlink:href=""></use>
         </svg>
         </div>
      Accept
     </button>
</form>
</div>
```

I want to use .click() on the button with class name 'class="btn btn-green"'.

I have used the following code to select the element (after following the solutions in other similar SO questions.

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".btn-green")
```

It looks like webdriver can find the element but when I try to apply .click() I get:

> ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible

I then did some digging into the element (thinking I could bypass by using x, y coordinates to click through) but after using .size and .location I get:

```
{'x': 0, 'y': 0}
{'height': 0, 'width': 0}
```

Any help you could give on how to get around this would be really appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I wonder why **Decline** is within an `<a>` tag & **Accept** within `<button>` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error hints to the potential problem, selenium does find it but it is not visible so you cannot click on it. You could check for visibility with `is_displayed` before clicking on it.   Another possibility is if there is another button with that class that is hidden, try to see if you can select a visible element in the browser console (Control+Shift+J) with `$(".btn-green")`

Some xpaths that might work that are more robust for your problem:

`//button[@type="submit" and text()="Accept"]`

`//button[@type="submit" and contains(@class, "btn-green")]`

Comment: There was another class which was hidden! Thanks! I solved by using the xpath of the visible element.

Comment: Sure. You can also accept the answer (checkmark) or click on the up arrow.  One more thing, the xpath you put is not very robust as if the page changes your xpath might not find the element anymore you might want to try //button[@type="submit" and contains(@class, "btn-green")], hopefully the other element that shares the class name is not a submit button

Answer (score 0):

To click on the *button* with text as **Accept** you can use the following line of code :

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button.btn.btn-green[type='submit']")
```